# spool multiple files in loop of shell script

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, shell, unix

I am trying to spool multiple files to reduce the manual work.

The SQL file (spool_csv.sql) have a select statement which i need to spool as a CSV file like below

```
set colsep ','
set linesize 9999
set trimspool on
set heading on
set pagesize 0 embedded on
set wrap off
set feedback off
set newpage 0
set verify off
set arraysize 5000
SET TERMOUT OFF
spool C:\Users\spool_csv\csv_03\csv_file_03-jan_&1..csv
select * from CRAFT_MVT_H where code = '&1';
spool off;
exit;
```

and then i have simple shell script (spool_csv.sh) which is looping through a file to pass parameter to SQL file and to change the name of spool file on runtime and also for where clause of SELECT statement.

```
for line in `cat chartfield1_03.txt`
do
  echo $line
  sqlplus -s user/password@SID @spool_03.sql $line
done
```

chartfield1_03.txt contains --

```
778
769
741 
728
739
759
737
752
710
734
747
```

i need to have separate csv file for each line (say value) of chartfield1_03.txt

so it will be like

```
csv_file_03-jan_778.csv
csv_file_03-jan_769.csv
csv_file_03-jan_741.csv
and so on....
```

but when i run the shell script it only creating one CSv file that is for last line of chartfield1_03.txt
i.e. csv_file_03-jan_747.csv

i am not sure why other file are not creating while i am passing the spool file as parameter and calling it in a loop so each time it should open a new SQL session and create the new spool file.

Please help me understand what i am missing here !!

So in the end i found out why it was not working as i missed to EOF in SQLPLUS command after adding this as below it is working fine.

**Solution as i find it.**

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in `cat chartfield1_03.txt`
do
  echo $line
  dt1 = `sqlplus -s HEW/hew_dba14@DEVHEW<<EOF
  whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
  @spool_03.sql $line;
EOF` &

done
```

Comment: but the echo works? do you get the number to the output?

Comment: yes the echo is working .
now i got the output as required please check the edited Question for solution.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create on each `sqlplus` execution the same file and rename it in shell. For this you can change line:

```
spool C:\Users\spool_csv\csv_03\csv_file_03-jan_&1..csv
```

to be

```
spool C:\Users\spool_csv\csv_03\csv_file_03-jan_..csv
```

and in shell script:

```
sqlplus -s user/password@SID @spool_03.sql $line
```

to be

```
sqlplus -s user/password@SID @spool_03.sql 
mv "C:\Users\spool_csv\csv_03\csv_file_03-jan_..csv" "C:\Users\spool_csv\csv_03\csv_file_03-jan_${line}.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply however i found the solution which is to add EOF for SQLPLUS command in shell. i will edit the to reflect the correct solution.

Comment: @mradul, you can add this as answer

Comment: Yes, just did :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution.

please provide any other solution if you have in your mind :)

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in `cat chartfield1_03.txt`
do
  echo $line
  dt1 = `sqlplus -s HEW/hew_dba14@DEVHEW<<EOF
  whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
  @spool_03.sql $line;
EOF` &

done
```